# Django consumer frequently get disconnected and reconnected on different pods on K8S

Tags: django, kubernetes, websocket

big brothers!
I deployed my Django app on K8S pods. I implemented websocket server with websocket consumer using Django channels package.
And the problem is, I found K8S would frequently close and reconnect websocket connection, that's to say K8S would frequently new consumer objects on the same websocket connection URL on different pods.
I have cached data inside consumer object, and this situation really bothers. How can I keep websocket connection in K8S?